# How to show in QComboBox a list of files in a folder c++ and Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

I want to show all files of a folder in a QComboBox. I've tested some things but is not what I'm looking.

```
void pacientes::on_mostrarPaciente_clicked()
{
 QDir path("C:/Users/Jaime/Desktop/interfaz/pacientes");
 QStringList files = path.entryList(QDir::Files);

 QComboBox comb;
 qDebug()<<files;
 comb.addItems(files);

 comb.show();

}
```

with qDebug is not showing nothing for console in this function. The qDebug in other function to show things, but in this function nothing. I think that not function well

Comment: Could you show us your current efforts?

Comment: according to your comment below my answer, the connection isn't actually connected. so here on_mostrarPaciente slot doesn't run. check your QObject::connect. or place the connection part of your code here.

Comment: that part the I'm doing with Qt Designer. I'm testing several configurations but still not works. I don't understand because all project works with Qt designer but not the Qcombobox. I will keep trying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
QDir path("d:/tmp");
QStringList files = path.entryList(QDir::Files);
QComboBox comb;
comb.addItems(files);
comb.show();
```

[image]

Comment: the program compile well, but in the QComboBox is not showing nothing

Comment: But mine has :) . try qDebug()<<files and see whether any outputs will be printed or not. Maybe your directory hasn't any files in it !

Comment: My function has to be wrong, the out is: `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_mostrarPaciente_clicked()`. In other function the qdebug do something.

Comment: the signal en Qt Designer was activated(String), i had `clicked` that it does not appear. I changed but nothing, I need to pass the String, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `QDir::entryInfoList()` with the filter set on files to get a `QFileInfoList`, then just add the information you want into the `QComboBox`.